# Inverting image colors in python

Tags: python, colors

I am trying to invert the colors of an image, I am currently stuck trying to figure out how to write the function to do so.

````
IMAGE_URL = "https://codehs.com/uploads/c709d869e62686611c1ac849367b3245"
IMAGE_WIDTH = 280
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 200

image = Image(IMAGE_URL)
image.set_position(70, 70)
image.set_size(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)
add(image)


# Write this function!
def invert_pixel(pixel):
    pass

# Applies invert filter to picture
def change_picture():
    for x in range(image.get_width()):
        for y in range(image.get_height()):
            pixel = image.get_pixel(x,y)
            new_colors = invert_pixel(pixel)
            image.set_red(x, y, new_colors[0])
            image.set_green(x, y, new_colors[1])
            image.set_blue(x, y, new_colors[2])
            

# Give the image time to load
print("Inverting Image ....")
print("Might take a minute....")
timer.set_timeout(change_picture, 1000)```
````

Comment: What do you thing does *invert* mean?

Comment: What is `Image` - show us your imports!

Comment: You should probably use Numpy here, the computation would be almost instant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `1` color scale, here is how:

```
def invert_pixel(pixel):
    return tuple(1 - c for c in pixel)
```

If you are using the `255` scale:

```
def invert_pixel(pixel):
    return tuple(255 - c for c in pixel)
```

Comment: I tried the function and I am getting the error:
Traceback (most recent call last): File VFS.browser.timer.py line 13, in f msg='{0.info}\n{0.__class__.__name__}: {0.args[0]}'.format(exc) File https://static.codehs.com/gulp/0a0c39c8fce8e3082eae782bc8478ca1aa2b06f3/abacus/brython-graphics.html?shouldResize=false&canvasWidth=400&canvasHeight=480/__main__ line 23, in change_picture image.set_red(x, y, new_colors[0]) TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @SeaPickle Edited to fix generator - array issue.